# Yaireo Tagify : tags deleted if selected a second time

Tags: jquery, tagify

I have a bug with the use of Yaireo Tagify: https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/.

I have an input field with a tag initialized in my value attribute and a select field with several options.

If I change the value of my select field, it updates my tag field (the current tag is replaced).

What I don't understand is that it only works if the value has never been added before.

For example my tag field is initialized to "Fêtes", if I add "Foires", "Fêtes" is replaced, if I add "Carnaval", idem it replaces "Foires", but if I select again "Fêtes" in my select field, nothing is displayed in my tag field... And if I select "Marchés", it appears well in my tag field, but if I change it to "Carnaval", nothing is displayed anymore, because already selected before...

Here is my script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.js-tags').tagify();

    if ($('input.js-tags').length && $('input.js-tags').data('url') === 'event_add') {

        $('#event_category').change(function() {
            
            let newCategoryName = $(this).find(':selected').text();

            if ($('tag[title="read-only category-tag"]').length) {

                let currentCategoryTagName = $('tag[title="read-only category-tag"]').find('.tagify__tag-text').text();

                $('input.js-tags').data('tagify').removeTags(currentCategoryTagName);
            }

            $('input.js-tags').data('tagify').addTags([
                {
                    value: newCategoryName,
                    readonly: true,
                    title: 'read-only category-tag'
                }
            ]);
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE : THE RELATED HTML**

```
<select id="event_category" name="event[category]" class="filter-input form-control" aria-describedby="event_category_help">
    <optgroup label="Fêtes">
        <option value="1">Fêtes</option>
        <option value="10">Carnavals</option>
        <option value="9">Fêtes foraines</option>
        <option value="8">Fêtes locales</option>
        <option value="11">Fêtes médiévales</option>
        <option value="53">Repas Festifs Réveillons</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Foires">
        <option value="2">Foires</option>
        <option value="13">Expositions</option>
        <option value="12">Salons</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Marchés">
        <option value="4">Marchés</option>
        <option value="22">Marchés bio</option>
        <option value="50">Marchés de créateurs</option>
        <option value="25">Marchés de Noël</option>
        <option value="23">Marchés de potiers</option>
        <option value="44">Marchés de Producteurs</option>
        <option value="27">Marchés estivaux</option>
        <option value="26">Marchés nocturnes</option>
        <option value="24">Marchés provencaux</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="event_tags" class="required">Tags *</label>
        <tags class="tagify filter-input js-tags form-control" required="" tabindex="-1">
            <tag title="read-only category-tag" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" class="tagify__tag tagify--noAnim" aria-readonly="true" __isvalid="true" readonly="true" value="Fêtes" contenteditable="false">
                <x title="" class="tagify__tag__removeBtn" role="button" aria-label="remove tag"></x>
                <div>
                    <span class="tagify__tag-text">Fêtes</span>
                </div>
            </tag>
            <span data-placeholder="​" aria-placeholder="" class="tagify__input" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-multiline="false" contenteditable=""></span>
        </tags>
        <input type="text" id="event_tags" name="event[tags]" required="required" class="filter-input js-tags form-control" value="[{&quot;value&quot;:&quot;F\u00eates&quot;,&quot;readonly&quot;:true,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;read-only category-tag&quot;}]" data-url="event_add" aria-describedby="event_tags_help">
        <small id="event_tags_help" class="form-text text-muted">Tapez un tag, faites "Entrée" ou "virgule", tapez un autre tag, etc.</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the related HTML Code

Comment: Here is the update above.

Comment: Got a Script error in Console

Comment: Got nothing in my console :/

Comment: By examining the inspector of my browser I realize that the value attribute of my tag field is not updated when the tag is deleted. So when the tag is replaced, the tag is visually replaced, but the value of the linked field is not updated (neither the old tag is deleted, nor the new tag is added). How to solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: You have to make it with select option dropdown link in this example. https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/qBZdOJe
I saw that there is a json whitelist with elements they can choosen from the select option. Use just one input field to connect it with tagify.